# Nema 17 stepper motor(ks42sth34-1504a) not working

Tags: stepper-motor

I am trying to connect a new Nema 17 stepper motor, ks42sth34-1504a, using TB6600.  It is a 6 wire stepper.  While measuring resistance for identifying coils, only one pair(1 and 3) shows any resistance, around 2.0.  All other combinations show no resistance.  I tried connecting the motor to TB6600 pairing 1-3 and 4-6 that makes the motor flutter.  Is this a broken motor? Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not going to have much luck until you identify the wires/terminals of *two* distinct independent coils.  Given six wires your coils are probably center tapped, so you need not only two pairs that show a suitable resistance between, but that show an open circuit to the other pair.  And ideally you'd match using both coils in the same half or full coil mode, though getting that wrong would probably at least lead to movement at reduced torque.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common pinout for bipolar steppers as follows:

1. Coil A
2. NC
3. Coil B'
4. Coil A'
5. NC
6. Coil B

That doesn't really match what you  say you are reading. While center-taps are possible, there needs to be two coils for this kind of stepper to have a hope of working (there are single phase steppers but they are used only in specialized applications).